# Finite dimensional normed vector space, projection continuous?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be an $n$ -dimensional normed $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. Let $\{e_i \mid i=1,...,n\}$ be a basis of $X$. Is it true that the function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\sum \lambda_i e_i \mapsto \lambda_i$ is continuous? I thought it would be easy to prove this but I wasn't able to.

Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: The norm in $X$ induces a topology,  namely open sets.

Comment: There are several theorems about finite dimensional normed linear spaces: any two norms are equivalent. any linear map on then is continuous etc. [These two theorems are easily seen to be equivalent]. They provide an answer to your question]. But if you want to avoid these theorems and use only the definition of norm you can look at my answer. @Jiu

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy In fact I was trying to prove that any two norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent. And I needed the continuity of $f$ for my proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof that does not use any theorem on general normed linear spaces. It uses only the Bolzano Weierstras Theorem for the usual norm on $\mathbb R^{n}$.  Suppose $\sum a_i^{(m)}e_i \to 0$. We have to show that $a_i^{(m)} \to 0$ for each $i$. We claim that $\{(a_{1}^{(m)},a_{2}^{(m)},...,a_{n}^{(m)})\}$ is bounded. Suppose, if possible, $\left\Vert
(a_{1}^{(m_{j})},a_{2}^{(m_{j})},...,a_{n}^{(m_{j})})\right\Vert_2 \to
\infty $. Here $\|.\|_2$ denotes the usual norm on $\mathbb R^{n}$.  Let $b_{i}^{(m_{j})}=\frac{a_{i}^{(m_{j})}}{\left\Vert
(a_{1}^{(m_{j})},a_{2}^{(m_{j})},...,a_{n}^{(m_{j})})\right\Vert_2 },1\leq
i\leq n.$ Then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}^{(m)}x_{i}\to 0$ and $%
\left\Vert (b_{1}^{(m_{j})},b_{2}^{(m_{j})},...,b_{n}^{(m_{j})})\right\Vert_2
=1$ $\forall j$. Since unit vectors form a compact set in $\mathbb R^{n}$ we can take limit of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}^{(m)}x_{i}$ through
a subsequence to get an equation of the type $
\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}x_{i}=0$ where $\left\Vert
(c_{1},c_{2},...,c_{n})\right\Vert_2 =1.$ This is impossible because $%
\{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}\}$ be a basis. We have proved that $%
\{(a_{1}^{(m)},a_{2}^{(m)},...,a_{n}^{(m)})\}$ is bounded. We now extract a
convergent subsequence of this sequence to get $
\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_{i}x_{i}=0$ forcing each $d_{i}$ to be $0$.  This shows
that every limit point of $\{(a_{1}^{(m)},a_{2}^{(m)},...,a_{n}^{(m)})\}$ is 
$(0,0,,,,0)$ and hence the claim is true.

Answer (score 2):

Since any two norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent, and $\|\sum_i \lambda_i e_i\|_* = \sum_i |\lambda_i|$ defines a norm, there exists a constant $C>0$ such that
$$
\|\sum_i \lambda_i e_i\|_*\leq C\|\sum_i \lambda_i e_i\|,\quad\forall (\lambda_i)_{i=1}^n.
$$It follows
$$
\left|f(\sum_i \lambda_i e_i)\right |= |\lambda_j|\le \|\sum_i \lambda_i e_i\|_*\leq C\|\sum_i \lambda_i e_i\|.$$

**EDIT:** Here's a sketch of the proof that any two norms on a f.d.v.s. $V$ on $\mathbb{F}$($=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) are equivalent. Let $(e_i)_{i=1}^n$ be a basis of $V$, and endow $V$ a norm defined by $\|\sum_i x_i e_i\|_1 =\sum_i |x_i|$. Then, $(V,\|\cdot\|_1)$ and $(\mathbb{F}^n,\|\cdot\|_1)$ are isometric and hence homeomorphic. Notice that this implies $\{\sum_i x_ie_i\;|\;\sum_i |x_i| = 1\}$ is compact in $V$.
Now, let $f(\sum_i x_ie_i) =\|\sum_i x_i e_i\|$ where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the given norm of $V$. If we show $\|\cdot\| \sim\|\cdot\|_1$, then the claim follows since $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. Observe that 
$$
|f(\sum_i x_ie_i)-f(\sum_i y_ie_i)| = |\|\sum_i x_ie_i\|-\|\sum_i y_ie_i\||\leq \|\sum_i (x_i-y_i)e_i\| \leq \sum_i |x_i-y_i|\cdot \max_i \|e_i\|.
$$ This shows $f:(V,\|\cdot\|_1)\to [0,\infty)$ is continuous. Since $E=\{\sum_i x_ie_i\;|\;\sum_i |x_i| = 1\}$ is compact, by extremum value theorem, there is $0<m\leq M<\infty$ such that
$$
m\leq f(x) =\|x\|\le M, \quad \forall x\in E.
$$ This gives $m \|x\|_1 \le \|x\|\le M\|x\|_1$ for all $x\in V$.

Comment: Is there a way to prove that two norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent without using the continuity of $f$? In other words, I want to make sure that it is not circular reasoning.

Comment: Yes, the proof I know uses only topological tools.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $P_1 v = v_1$.  Observe
\begin{align}
|v_1-w_1| = |P_1v-P_1w| \leq \|P_1\|\|v-w\|.
\end{align}

**Edit**: A upon the request of @KaviRamaMurthy, I have decided to include a quick proof that all linear maps $A:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ are bounded.

Using matrix representation, we see that
\begin{align}
\|Av\|^2=&\ \sum^n_{j=1}\left|\sum^n_{j=1} a_{ij}v_j \right|^2 \leq \sum^n_{j=1}\left( \sum^n_{j=1} |a_{ij}|^2\right)\left( \sum^n_{j=1} |v_j|^2\right) \\
=&\ \left(\sum^n_{i,j=1}|a_{ij}|^2 \right)\|v\|^2
\end{align}
which means $\|Av\| \leq C\|v\|$ where $C$ is independent of $v$.

Comment: The norm given is an arbitrary norm.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It is valid for the usual norm on Euclidean spaces, not for a general norm.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think the answer is okay. Observe $|v_1-w_1| = \|v_1 \mathbf{e}_1 - w_1\mathbf{e}_1\| = \|P_1 v-P_1w\|\leq \|P_1\|_\text{op} \|v-w\|$

Comment: You have not understood the question. you are assuming what you are asked to prove. You are asked to show that $P_1$ is a continuous map. How can you assume that it is a bounded operator to prove that it is continuous? @Jacky Chong

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I guess I'm assuming all linear maps on finite dimensional vector spaces are bounded.

Comment: With that assumption your proof is fine, but OP has already made it clear that he wants an independent proof.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have updated the post.

Comment: This edit does not address the question I have raised. You have proved that linear maps of $\mathbb R^{n}$ with USUAL norm are continuous but what you need is the fact that linear maps from given norm to usual norm are continuous. The question asked here is just not as easy as you think it is.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Looking at the comments you had with the OP I see that there are two problems being addressed. I simply answered what was asked in the original post before the remark by the OP about trying to prove all norms are equivalent on finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: Any how, I did misinterpret the problem.